# removing extra space after a div in boostrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In a formgroup i have two element one is label another one is button but i am getting extra spaces between the button and label.
See this fiddle. [myFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohel3csedu/yx58b5uL/3/)

I want to remove the space between DocumentType and Attach a file

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
        <h3> panel heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control">Document Type</label>
          <label class="fileUpload">
            <input id="documentattachment" name="documentattachment" multiple type="file" /> Attach a file
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
          </select>
          <div id="submitButton">
            <button data-bind="click: submitFile" class="form-control">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `margin` on `label` & also remove this `fileUpload`

```
label{margin-bottom:0;}

.fileUpload {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  /*margin: 2px;*/
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yx58b5uL/5/

Answer (score 1):

There is a `margin-bottom` coming from bootstrap for label. Use:

```
label.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

and there you go. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.fileUpload input[type="file"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: -1000px;
}
.fileUpload {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}
.fileUpload:hover {
  background: #CCC;
}
.fileUpload:active {
  background: #CCF;
}
.fileUpload:invalid + span {
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}
.fileUpload:valid + span {
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}
label.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <h3>
    panel heading
  </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control">Document Type</label>
          <label class="fileUpload">
            <input id="documentattachment" name="documentattachment" multiple type="file" />Attach a file
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
          </select>
          <div id="submitButton">
            <button data-bind="click: submitFile" class="form-control">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As bootstrap CSS by default margin is there for label so you need remove this.

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yx58b5uL/8/)

```
 label{margin-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS.  Add an ID or Class to the "Document Type" label, and set the margin to 0.

CSS:

```
    .fileUpload input[type="file"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: -1000px;
}

.fileUpload {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}

.fileUpload:hover {
  background: #CCC;
}

.fileUpload:active {
  background: #CCF;
}

.fileUpload:invalid + span {
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}

.fileUpload:valid + span {
  color: rgba(171, 68, 70, 1);
}

#noSpace {
  margin: 0;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="panel">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <h3>
    panel heading
  </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label id="noSpace" class="form-control">Document Type</label>
          <label class="fileUpload">
            <input id="documentattachment" name="documentattachment" multiple type="file" /> Attach a file
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
          </select>
          <div id="submitButton">
            <button data-bind="click: submitFile" class="form-control">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a link to the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/yx58b5uL/6/

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maky/yx58b5uL/9/